# Rooted Galaxy Nexus GSM silently fails to reflash/erase - Unable to wipe and its rebooting continiously

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-nexus, troubleshooting

I have been struggling for a week. Searching all though the internet.

My Galaxy Nexus has suddenly stopped working. It is continuously rebooting.

Its rooted but has stock rom 4.3.

My problem is, I thought of wipe everything and do a fresh flash and I started with fastboot commands.

So I ran all the commands below:

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-maguro-primelc04.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader

fastboot flash radio radio-maguro-i9250xxlj1.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
```

Both went well with out errors and OKAY for all erasing, sending and writing.

This was taking endless time.

```
fastboot -w update image-yakju-jwr66y.zip
```

So, I disconnected. And now:

I am unable to Flash or wipe partitions or even a single file (from fastboot or recovery screens - wherever applicable)!!!

I am not able to erase and do a fresh install. The height of the situation is when recovery is falking me showing that the files and folders are deleted, but after a reboot all files and folders which I just deleted are coming up in list!

Moreever, when I do a `./fastboot oem lock` (the bootloader screen shows that the lock status is locked) and do a reboot, the lock status again turns UNLOCKED!

I tried to flash the latest TWRP.

```
fastboot flash recovery openrecovery-twrp-2.7.0.0-maguro.img
fastboot reboot-bootloader
```

Its showing successs. But when I run it after reboot, its my earlier version 2.6 of twrp shows up!

I am not sure what is causing this! but please help me recover my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching lots of forum, chatting with experts in XDA, I found out that:

> Samsung used a cheap substandard emmc.

I have tried everything from adb, Odin to jtag. The emmc just died,no way to fix it.

First there was this awful lag issue : [Galaxy Nexus GSM bad eMMC chip type V3U00M phone is almost unusable](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43081)

Later within 2 years, **emmc will die** and you will stuck with bootloop issue : 
[Galaxy Nexus GT-I9250 with hardlocked NAND ?!? need help !](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/galaxy-nexus-gt-i9250-hardlocked-nand-t2770955)
[Galaxy Nexus S (i9250) stuck in reboot loop - gets to OS loading and restarts](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/help/galaxy-nexus-s-i9250-stuck-reboot-loop-t2900257)

Almost all of us with V3U00M chip and other defective mmc chips would have now got there emmc fried.

> What to say, on my side I'm blacklisting Samsung, this phone has been a joke for me since the beginning (the fstrim bug has been a nightmare), if you dare you can try to replace the board.